# How to display error messages using jQuery?

Tags: visualforce, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.f').Click(function(){
        alert('Happy New Year');
       var status1 = $('.b').val();
                    if(status1=='open') {
                        alert(status1);   
                            $('.b').text("Status Field Should not be Open");
                        }
                    });});
 <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save1}" styleClass="f"/>
```

Comment: Hello Sai, can you describe what problem you are facing?

Comment: How to display error messages in vf page using jquery

Comment: Do you want to display salesforce style error messages?

Comment: yes, i want to display  salesforce style error messages

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apex:pageMessage` to display individual message on VF page

This is a kind of static message which you will write in visualforce itself, and can put some conditions in rendered attribute to display the message.

```
<apex:pageMessage id="mymessage" severity="Error" summary="First Error message on page" strength="1"></apex:pageMessage>
```

This would render to

[image]

severity can be anything from 'confirm', 'info', 'warning', 'error'.

This will render below html code

```
<div id="page:mymessage:j_id0:j_id2" class="messageText">
    <span id="page:mymessage:j_id0:j_id3">
    <h4></h4>
    </span>
    First Error message on page<br>
</div>
```

> Html Id can very according to your code

You can easily manipulate this code using jQuery and HTML Id.

Example

```
$("[id*=page:mymessage]").each(function() {
 this.style.display = "none";
 });
```

[To Know more in Detail](http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/apexpagemessage-and-apexpagemessages-salesforce/)